# Arrange Code in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, coding-style

Is there a way to arrange the code in Visual Studio automatically (built-in functionality or an extension)?

By arrange, I don't mean format, which I know of. I mean to place private fields, public properties, constructors, private/public methods in a certain manner automatically. I've developed an application, but I had longer pauses in development, resulting in not-uniformed code style throughout the project. Is there a way to automate the process of rearranging it to comply to a certain style or do I have to do it all manually?

Comment: Have you seen StyleCop (https://stylecop.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use CodeMaid from Visual Studio Extension Gallery. It has a feature where you reorganize the current file by right clicking inside the editor then in the context menu click on Reorganize. It will organize the file by accessibility.

http://www.codemaid.net/

The features are listed on their homepage.